# Parsing a RESTful PUT

Tags: java, rest

How do I access the HTTP PUT message (JSON format) in a Java server application?  The HTTP PUT is sent from a Python client.

Python Client so far:

```
    import http.client 
    import urllib

    values = {'s':'basic','submit':'search'}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)


    headers = headers['Content-length']=str(len(bytes(data, 'utf-8')))
    connection =  http.client.HTTPConnection('localhost',8080)
    connection.request("PUT", "/file", body=data.encode("utf-8"))
```

When PUT gets to the Java server - how do I get the message (data from Python)?

So far, this is what I have in Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class JavaServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String fromclient;

        ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (8080);

        System.out.println("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 8080");

        Socket connected = Server.accept();
        System.out.println( " THE CLIENT"+" "+ connected.getInetAddress() +":"+connected.getPort()+" IS CONNECTED ");

        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connected.getInputStream()));

        fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println( "RECIEVED:" + fromclient );

    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information than this

Comment: Are you using plain java or a server with java ee?

Comment: plain java but will put it on an apache server

Answer (score 2):

You will need to iterate over your "inFromClient"

So something like:

```
    while((fromclient = inFromClient.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println( "RECIEVED:" + fromclient );
    }
    inFromClient.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. That did work. I also just found this StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(); String line; while ((line = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) { buffer.append(line); } System.out.println("buffer.toString = " + buffer.toString());

Which also works, however, the json message seems to have a lot of extra characters and seems to be mixed up. I am new at working with JSON. Maybe that is normal or I need double quotes around it. I am actually sending times and ip addresses and values. Do numbers require special formatting with JSON?

Comment: good it worked out, I have problem in testing it, because it doesn't get out of the loop. Anyhow I changed the feedback! cheers! =)

Comment: I noticed that aswell.  When the pythonclient exits the the loop exits. The python code probably needs correction.

Comment: if you wanted to get the data in a json format you could format the data you are passing as json.  So don't parse.urlencode. import json and do json.dumps(values), then pass that into your put request.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. That did work.
I also just found this:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
buffer.append(line);
}

System.out.println("buffer.toString = " + buffer.toString());
```

Which also works, however, the json message seems to have a lot of extra characters and seems to be mixed up. I am new at working with JSON. Maybe that is normal or I need double quotes around it. I am actually sending times and ip addresses and values. Do numbers require special formatting with JSON?